# How to use multiple decoration in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, decorator, python-decorators

I have a function where I want to use multiple decorators.

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      (requests.exceptions.Timeout,
                       requests.exceptions.ConnectionError))
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

```
@timeit
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

Can I combine the two decorators?

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      (requests.exceptions.Timeout,
                       requests.exceptions.ConnectionError))
@timeit
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

Or what would happen if I want to handle more errors, i.e.:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      SomeOtherError)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      (requests.exceptions.Timeout,
                       requests.exceptions.ConnectionError))
@timeit
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

But then how the decoratos would behave?

- For example if there is an exception, which timing `timeit` would show?

Comment: This can't be answered generally. Multiple decorators may or may not work or work only in a particular order.

Comment: Decorators are applied inside out, i.e. applying the inner decorator `@timeit` returns a new function, to which the outer decorator is then applied.  So if you put `@timeit`  on the inside it will measure timing of each individual retry, if you put it on the outside it will measure timing of all the retries until the inner func eventually returns